# Even Administrators Can Log in as Any User is enabled ,still not able to see login option

Tags: profile, permissions, user-management, grant-login-access

My profile is System Administrator and i enabled **Administrators Can Log in as Any User is enabled** but still i cannot see login option for any user

Comment: is the user active?

Comment: What edition SF are you using? Did you upgrade from a lower edition (if so, which)?

Comment: Its Salesforce Unlimited edition

Comment: Strange.  No recent upgrade?

Comment: Was your org migrated from professional edition?